# how to press tap and hold and scroll down using webdriverio and appium

Tags: javascript, appium, webdriver-io

how to press tap and hold and scroll down using webdriverio and appium. I have used a normal scroll but nothing seems to work. I can manually hold and swipe but the below commands does not work

This is what I tried, however, I am not able to achieve anything with it:

```
browser.touchAction([
                { action: 'longPress'},
                { action: 'moveTo', x: -10, y: 0},
                { action: 'release'}
            ])
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void fingerSwipe(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY, long timeInMillis){
    PointerInput touchAction = new PointerInput(PointerInput.Kind.TOUCH, "touchAction");
    Interaction moveToStart = touchAction.createPointerMove(Duration.ZERO, PointerInput.Origin.viewport(), startX, startY);
    Interaction pressDown = touchAction.createPointerDown(PointerInput.MouseButton.LEFT.asArg());
    Interaction moveToEnd = touchAction.createPointerMove(Duration.ofMillis(timeInMillis), PointerInput.Origin.viewport(), endX, endY);
    Interaction pressUp = touchAction.createPointerUp(PointerInput.MouseButton.LEFT.asArg());

    Sequence swipe = new Sequence(touchAction, 0);
    swipe.addAction(moveToStart);
    swipe.addAction(pressDown);
    swipe.addAction(moveToEnd);
    swipe.addAction(pressUp);

    driver.perform(Arrays.asList(swipe));
}
```

I use selenium interactions package to perform a swipe using JAVA and appium.
Try using something similar to above code in WebDriverIo for Appium versions - 1.15.0 and above. You just need to pass input parameters depending upon the swipe you want to perform.

'long timeInMillis' is the time period of the swipe.

Comment: sorry but i am asking for a webdriverio and this does not work for me

Answer (score 1):

I used the following to scroll down for my appium python project

```
for each in range(1, 2):
            driver.swipe(500, 1700, 500, 1000, 400)
```

Change the for loop according to the number of swipes you need

Comment: i dont think i have anything similar in webdriveri io

Answer (score 0):

I used this:

```
  await browser.touchPerform([
    { action: 'press', options: { x: 500, y: 1280 }},
    { action: 'wait', options: { ms: 1000}},
    { action: 'moveTo', options: { x: 500, y:  347}},
    { action: 'release' }
  ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

to swipe left with the element

- webdriverio: `8.3.2`
- Appium 2
- Javascript
- platform: Android real device

```
const elem = driver.$(`~${accessibilityLabel}`)
const width = await elem.getSize('width')
const startX = width / 2
const endX = startX - 150
await elem.touchAction([
      {action: 'press', x: startX, y: 0},
      {action: 'wait', ms: 1000},
      {action: 'moveTo', x: endX, y: 0},
      'release',
    ])
```

note: start x=0 and y=0 is because the actions are relative to element